# How to solve a system of linear inequalities?

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

I am working on the following exercise:

> Find a solution to the following system or prove that none exists:
>
> \begin{align}
> x_1-x_2 &\le 4\\
> x_1-x_5 &\le 2\\
> x_2-x_4 &\le -6 \\
> x_3-x_2 &\le 1 \\
> x_4-x_1 &\le 3 \\
> x_4-x_3 &\le 5\\
> x_4-x_5 &\le 10 \\
> x_4-x_3 &\le -4 \\
> x_5-x_4 &\le -8
> \end{align}

I do not know how to do that. Is there some algorithm? I can not find anything online. Could you help me?

Comment: you might want to google "linear programming"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose a solution exists.  Then add up the third, fourth, and eighth constraints
$$(x_2 - x_4) + (x_3 - x_2) + (x_4 - x_3) \le -6+1-4 \\    
$$
to obtain the contradiction
$0 \le -9$.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, just hit it with a hammer until it stops bleeding.

You can add $x_i - x_j \le a$ and $x_j - x_k \le b$ to get $x_i - x_k \le a+b$ and if you have $x_i - x_k$ anywhere....

So $x_1 - x_2 + x_2 - x_4=x_1-x_4  \le 4+(-6) = -2$.  And $x_4 -x_1 \le 3$ so $-3 \le x_1 - x_4 \le -2$.

And $x_1 -x_5 + x_5 -x_4 = x_1 - x_4 \le 2+(-8) = -6$.  Which contradicts the above.

Answer (score 2):

From the first inequality you have $$x_1 \leq 4+x_2.$$
Now from the second $$4+x_2-x_5 \leq 2$$ or $$ x_2-x_5 \leq -2$$ or $$x_2 \leq -2+x_5.$$
Now from the third you get $$ -2+x_5-x_4\leq -6$$ or $$x_5\leq -4+x_4.$$ This can be applied to the last inequality and you get $$-4+x_4-x_4\leq -8$$ and that gives $$-4 \leq -8.$$ So the system has no solution.