# How to find a solution to an inequality system?

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

I need to find a solution to the following system of linear inequalities:

\begin{align}
x_1-x_2 &\le 1\\
x_1-x_4 &\le -4 \\
x_2-x_3 &\le 2 \\
x_2-x_5 &\le 7  \\
x_2-x_6 &\le 5 \\
x_3-x_6 &\le 10 \\
x_4-x_2 &\le 2  \\
x_5-x_1 &\le -1 \\
x_5-x_4 &\le 3 \\
x_6-x_3 &\le -8
\end{align}

In contrast to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452354/how-to-solve-a-system-of-linear-inequalities/3452402#3452402) there should be a solution for this system. Is there any systematic way to find a solution?

Comment: Linear programming is designed for this.

Comment: @DonThousand On the contrary, linear programming doesn't find the solution to the inequalities,  This would require finding all the vertices of the simplex, rather than just one at which the optimum of the objective function (lacking here) is attained.

Comment: @saulspatz True, I just meant the general style of problem.

Comment: What do you mean by a solution?  The solution set is a region in $6$-dimensional space, formed by the intersection of $10$ closed half-spaces.  What form do you expect a solution to take that is simpler than what is given?  If the solution set turns out to be bounded, it's the convex hull of a finite number of points.  Is that what you want?  What if the solution set isn't bounded?

Comment: @saulspatz: I need a concrete solution vector $(x_1,...,x_6)$.

Comment: Any one of the infinitely many solutions will do?

Comment: Yes. But I do not see how to systematically find one

Comment: You can introduce slack variable, for example, $s_1 = 1 - x_1 + x_2$. This gives you an augmented system. Then, as suggested solve an LP minimizing the sum of these slack variables. If the minimum is 0, then you have a solution. Otherwise, you do not

Comment: @Pebeto Isn't this the same as changing all the $\geq$ signs to = and solving the system of equations?  If that's right, I don't see how this can work, because we'll have both $x_3-x_6=10$ and $x_6-x_3=-8$.

Comment: @saulspatz, no, this is not the same. The slack variables are extra variables. In your example, you will get $x_3 - x_6 +s_1 = 1-$ and $x_6-x_3+s_2 = - 8$

Comment: @Pebeto Thanks, but I still don't see it, I'm afraid.  Aren't you requiring the slack variables to be $\geq0$, so that a minimum of $0$ for the sum means all the $s_i=0$?  If so, that gives the contradiction I mentioned.  If not, why does a minimum of $0$ indicate that a solution exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using linear programming (LP) with a constant zero objective, I found the following feasible solution:
$$x=(-6, 0, 2, 8, -7, 0).$$

By the way, this LP is the dual of a network LP, hence the constraint matrix is [totally unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Total_unimodularity).

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear program without an objective.  Algorithms for solving linear programs include the simplex algorithm (Phase I is enough when there is no objective), the ellipsoid algorithm, and many others.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm